# Animating height

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to show/hide an element by modifying it's `height`. Here is an example code showing my issue:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    id: win
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true

    ColumnLayout {
        width: parent ? parent.width : 200


        Switch {
            id: someswitch
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
        }

        Label {
            id: myText
            text: "dummy"
            height: 0

            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            clip: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter

            states: State {
                name: "visible"
                when: someswitch.checked
                PropertyChanges { target: myText; height: implicitHeight }
            }

            Behavior on height {
                NumberAnimation { duration: 100 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't add a `Transition`/`Animation` yet, but the behavior is already wrong on this stage. `someswitch` is unchecked by default but the text is shown. On the other hand, after checking the switch, the text hides and never appears back.

How should I handle that? I'd like the text to "slide out". I don't want to change its `opacity`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, `State`s consistency should be guaranteed to ensure that `Transition`s work properly. Consistency can be achieved either:

- by defining a *consistent* default state
- by defining *all* the necessary `State`s, like the other nice answer proposed.

That begin said, it should be noted that the presence of a `Layout` plays a *key role* here. The `Layout` somewhat *supersedes* the `height` settings of the `Items` with its `minimumHeight` property. In such a scenario `State`s defined over `height` does *not* really affect the `Label`. The obvious solution is to force `State`s consistency but over `Layout.preferredHeight`, i.e. define the default `State` as well as the `"invisible"` with different values for `Layout.preferredHeight` instead of `height`. A revisited version of your code could look like this:

```
Label {
    id: myText
    text: "dummy"
    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
    clip: true
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
    Layout.preferredHeight: implicitHeight   //visible --> layout height = text implicit height

    states: State {
            name: "invisible"
            when: !someswitch.checked
            PropertyChanges { target: myText; Layout.preferredHeight: 0 }  // invisible --> layout item height forced to zero
        }

    Behavior on Layout.preferredHeight {
        NumberAnimation { duration: 100 }
    }
}
```

A fully working example can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=3i9aWHLx) (whereas a version with a "visible" state can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=xWcnbcT7)).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `States` and `Transition` in your case. For example:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    width: 600
    height: 600
    visible: true

    CheckBox {
        text: "hide/show"
        id: someswitch
        x: 10
        y: 10
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: mytext
        width: parent.width
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "orange"
        state: "shown"
        states: [
            State {
                name: "shown"
                when: !someswitch.checked
                PropertyChanges { target: mytext; height: 300 }
            },
            State {
                name: "hidden"
                when: someswitch.checked
                PropertyChanges { target: mytext; height: 0 }
            }
        ]
        transitions: Transition {
             PropertyAnimation { property: "height"; duration: 500; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though `someswitch` is not checked by default, the text is shown. After checking and unchecking it, works as expected. My code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12313265/